# Bad page display when search terms include char /

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess, search

I have an URL that display the results of a search. My .htaccess looks like this:

`Options FollowSymLinks
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
Rewriterule ^search-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-([0-9]+)$ basic.php?token=$1&service=$2&location=$3&pageNumber=$4`

When `service` or `location` doesn't include any special char the query works perfectly, but if someone search something like `c/ street Name` or simply the search string includes `\` (backslash) my application shows the search page but with no styles (only plain text and no button works).

I guess this is happening because the URL is like `http://domain.com/search-token-lawyer-c/street%name` and the `/` char is creating the trouble.

How can I  fix it?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add in your `basic.php` html header code:

```
<base href="/">
```

Comment: Now all searchs looks like the search page with no styles

Comment: Use absolute link for css file (or relative to root with `/directory/...`)

Comment: Ok fixed, thanks for giving the hint.

I included <base href="http://www.domain.com">